# How do I download file metadata from a SharePoint site?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint site and I would like to download all files and their metadata (specifically, the name of the creator and the name of the modifier for each time the file was modified, as well as the date of modification).  I can see this metadata in the user interface, so I know it is available.

I have set up access to the SharePoint site via SharePoint Online Management Shell, and I am running it as an admin.  I've followed all the [steps](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568015.aspx) for connecting to SharePoint, and I've confirmed that these steps have executed correctly.

However, when I try to deploy [this](http://www.nikcraik.ca/sharepoint-powershell-script-to-extract-all-documents-and-their-versions/) script (substituting the 13th line with the name of my site), it errors out on the 'Get-SPWeb' cmdlet.  Do I need to make other modifications to this script?

I am aware that there are other scripts for downloading SharePoint files, but I need to use this one because a SharePoint admininstrator told me that it would work in conjunction with a second script which extracts the metadata, found here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/get-file-meta-data-function-f9e8d804

Comment: This seems like really bad advice from your SharePoint Developer. Metadata is built in with classes - why reinvent the wheel? You should be able to use this class https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.id.aspx

Unfortunately I'm unfamiliar with PowerShell and could only provide an answer in C# for you however I do believe that class exists in PowerShell as well.

Comment: If you are trying to download only metadata than you can use **Export to Excel** option available on **Library** tab of **Document Library**

Comment: Thank you for your replies - I realized I didn't ask my question very clearly and have modified it accordingly.  @Santosha Epili - the discovery of Export to Excel was very helpful (but it doesn't export an entry for each instance in which the file has been modified - which is what I want (FYI, I do have versioning turned on).   ElvisLikeBear - I'm looking into the VB script of the link you provided - thank you.

Comment: I made some progress - I downloaded a module with Get-SPWeb from https://powershell.codeplex.com/releases/view/104773, and put it into the path for powershell modules (discoverable by typing $env:PSModulePath).  Now, my problem is that when I try to run the code, the console says 'Get-SPWeb' was found, but could not be loaded.

Comment: More progress: I wasn't able to open the modules from codeplex, but the contents of the files are available here: https://powershell.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#PowerSharePoint/PowerSharePoint.psm1.  So I copy-pasted the 'Get-SPWeb' function and tacked it onto the end of my code (you can see the tacked-together code here: http://www.archivalscience.ca/sharepoint.txt).  The good news: there are no red lines in the PS console after I run the code.  The bad news: there is nothing in the export folders :-(

Comment: I recently discovered the SharePoint StackExchange, and reposted this question there.  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149611/how-do-i-download-documents-from-sharepoint-online

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to solve:

- Go to the relevant SharePoint site and click the 'Sync' button.
- Go to your OneDrive and see if the SharePoint site shows up as a folder.
- Get OneDrive folderpath.
- Run this Boe Prox script in PowerShell (using the OneDrive folderpath.)

```
Function Get-FolderItem {
    
        [cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Filter')]
        Param (
            [parameter(Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
            [Alias('FullName')]
            [string[]]$Path = $PWD,
            [parameter(ParameterSetName='Filter')]
            [string[]]$Filter = '*.*',    
            [parameter(ParameterSetName='Exclude')]
            [string[]]$ExcludeFile,              
            [parameter()]
            [int]$MaxAge,
            [parameter()]
            [int]$MinAge
        )
        Begin {
            $params = New-Object System.Collections.Arraylist
            $params.AddRange(@("/L","/E","/NJH","/BYTES","/FP","/NC","/XJ","/R:0","/W:0","T:W","/UNILOG:c:\temp\test.txt"))
            If ($PSBoundParameters['MaxAge']) {
                $params.Add("/MaxAge:$MaxAge") | Out-Null
            }
            If ($PSBoundParameters['MinAge']) {
                $params.Add("/MinAge:$MinAge") | Out-Null
            }
        }
        Process {
            ForEach ($item in $Path) {
                Try {
                    $item = (Resolve-Path -LiteralPath $item -ErrorAction Stop).ProviderPath
                    If (-Not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $item -Type Container -ErrorAction Stop)) {
                        Write-Warning ("{0} is not a directory and will be skipped" -f $item)
                        Return
                    }
                    If ($PSBoundParameters['ExcludeFile']) {
                        $Script = "robocopy `"$item`" NULL $Filter $params /XF $($ExcludeFile  -join ',')"
                    } Else {
                        $Script = "robocopy `"$item`" NULL $Filter $params"
                    }
                    Write-Verbose ("Scanning {0}" -f $item)
                    Invoke-Expression $Script | Out-Null
                    get-content "c:\temp\test.txt" | ForEach {
                        Try {
                            If ($_.Trim() -match "^(?<Children>\d+)\s(?<FullName>.*)") {
                               $object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                                    FullName = $matches.FullName
                                    #Extension = $matches.fullname -replace '.*\.(.*)','$1'
                                    #FullPathLength = [int] $matches.FullName.Length
                                    #FileHash = Get-FileHash -LiteralPath "\\?\$($matches.FullName)" |Select -Expand Hash
                                    #Created = ([System.IO.FileInfo] $matches.FullName).creationtime
                                    #Created = ([System.IO.FileInfo] "\\?\$($matches.FullName)").creationtime
                                    LastWriteTime = ([System.IO.FileInfo] "\\?\$($matches.FullName)").LastWriteTime
                                    #Characters = (Get-Content -LiteralPath "\\?\$($matches.FullName)" | Measure-Object -ignorewhitespace -Character).Characters
                                    #Size = ([System.IO.FileInfo] "\\?\$($matches.FullName)").length
                                    #Access = ((Get-Acl -LiteralPath "\\?\$($matches.FullName)") |Select -Expand AccessToString)-replace '[\r\n]',' '
                                    #$permission = (Get-Acl $Folder).Access | ?{$_.IdentityReference -match $User} | Select IdentityReference,FileSystemRights
                                    #Owner = (Get-ACL $matches.Fullname).Owner
                                } 
                                $object.pstypenames.insert(0,'System.IO.RobocopyDirectoryInfo')
                                Write-Output $object
                            } Else {
                                Write-Verbose ("Not matched: {0}" -f $_)
                            }
                        } Catch {
                            Write-Warning ("{0}" -f $_.Exception.Message)
                            Return
                        }
                    }
                } Catch {
                    Write-Warning ("{0}" -f $_.Exception.Message)
                    Return
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
 $a = Get-FolderItem "C:\Your\OneDrive\Here" | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\Output.csv -Encoding Unicode
```